# How to automatically add a default team to a newly created repository

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I'm looking for a way to automatically add a team to newly-added repositories that are tied to an organization on GitHub.

The method I'm currently considering is using GitHub's REST API to get all repositories linked to an organization, and automatically executing GitHub Actions to add a team from the same organization to those repositories every day.

However, I think that GitHub Actions, which is a pay-as-you-go system, is not good in terms of efficiency.

Is there a way to add a team to multiple repositories automatically other than GitHub Actions?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct here. GitHub lacks an inherent feature for automatically assigning a default team to each newly created repository. Nevertheless, this functionality can be achieved by utilizing GitHub's API and implementing a straightforward script that executes whenever a new repository is generated.

Outlined below are the fundamental steps to establish this setup:

1. Create a Server to Receive the Webhook: Develop a server capable of receiving incoming Webhook requests. This server can be a small application coded in languages like Python, Node.js, or Ruby. Upon receiving a request, the server should parse the event and extract essential information, such as the new repository's name and the organization to which it belongs.
2. Set up a Webhook: Within your organization settings, you can establish a new Webhook. Configure this Webhook to listen for the repository event, which triggers whenever a repository is created, deleted, made public, or made private.

   To do this you need to go to your ogranization, select webhooks and click add webhook:

[image]

Choose `Let me select individual events.` And mark `Repositories`

[image]

3. Utilize the GitHub API to Assign the Team: After gathering the necessary details, the server can make a request to the GitHub API to assign a team to the repository. This operation requires using the PUT /orgs/{org}/teams/{team_slug}/repos/{owner}/{repo} endpoint. Remember to replace the placeholders {org}, {team_slug}, {owner}, and {repo} with your organization's name, the team's slug, the repository owner's username, and the new repository's name, respectively.

Here you have an example how to handle listening for different event with [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/monitor-github-events-with-a-function-triggered-by-a-webhook/).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I was just wondering if you have any resources for me to fall back on, in case I didn't quite completely grasp everything. Nevertheless, still a great response!

Comment: Hey. I added some details. Still not full example but it is getting closer.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to the answer! I'll make sure to try it out and give an update as to whether I can utilize this or not soon!