# Automatically add a team to newly created repositories of the same organization

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I am looking for a way to add a team `test-team` to a repository owned an organization called `test-org`. The team is already inside the organization.

I have already known how to add a team to a repository using GitHub Actions, and I have also known how to list all of the repositories I am currently a member in in the `test-org` organization.

At first I thought it was just a case of creating a new repository with a workflow already built into it, but it led to nowhere. I do believe that this should be implemented as organization-scope Actions, not repository-scope (the action must be implemented on the organization itself, and not on the repository), but I am not pretty sure.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a team to multiple repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76808447/add-a-team-to-multiple-repositories)

Comment: Not really. I want to add the same team to every newly created repository of that organization. I want it to be something that automatically triggers whenever a new repository is created. I also want to use GitHub Actions along with NodeJS in order to do so.

Comment: Did you read whole? It does exactly what you want, add a team whenever a new repository is created. In which aspect it doesn't solve your case?

Comment: Ah, I just read it again & it seems like I asked the same question. Oops!

Comment: No worries. The title is slightly misleading. I will change this.

Comment: If you consider my reply there helpful please upvote it.